# Client.PostAsync (with Json) Gets 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create an Integration Test for my .Net Core Web Api

But I am always getting a 400 Bad Request response. I am sharing details below

Here is my Controller method

```
public IActionResult UpdateProductById([FromBody]int id, string description)
{
    var result = ProductService.UpdateProductById(id, description);
    if (result.Exception == null)
        return Ok(result);
    else
        return BadRequest(result.Exception.Message);
}
```

Here is my test class (which tries to post)

```
[Fact]
public async Task UpdateProductById_Test_WithProduct()
{
    var product = new
    {
        id = 1,
        description = "foo"
    };

    var productObj= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);

    var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(productObj);
    var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);

    byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    var result = await _tester.Client.PostAsync("/api/1.0/UpdateProductById", byteContent);

    result.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: Hi, what's in the exception message?

Comment: You're hiding the real error when you call 'BadRequest'.

Comment: PoulBak and Stefan problem solved with Nkosi's comment. Thank you so much for your interest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test is sending all the content in the body of the request, yet the action is only binding the `id`. Most likely the description is null and causing an issue with the update.

Create a model to hold the data

```
public class ProductModel {
    public int id { get; set; } 
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Refactor action to get the content from the body of the request

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateProductById([FromBody]ProductModel model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        var result = ProductService.UpdateProductById(model.id, model.description);
        if (result.Exception == null)
            return Ok(result);
        else
            return BadRequest(result.Exception.Message);
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```